# Importing Data MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a huge dataset what is the faster way to upload data in MySQL PHP database and is there anyway to verify all datas are imported or not.

Any suggestion or hints will be greatly appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the data set is simply huge (can be transferred within hours), it is not worth the effort of finding an efficient way - any script should be able to do the job. I am assuming you are reading from some non-db format (eg. plain text) ? In that way, simply read, and insert.

If you require careful processing before you insert the rows, you might want to consider creating real objects in memory and their sub-objects first and then mapping them to rows and tables - Object-Relational data source patterns will be valuable here. This will, however, be much slower, and I would not recommend it unless it's absolutely necessary, especially if you are doing it just once.

For very fast access, some people wrote a direct binary blob of objects on the disk and then read it directly into an array, but that is available in languages like C/C++; I am not sure if/how it can be used in a scripted language. Again, this is good for READING the data back into memory, not transferring to DB.

The easiest way to verify that the data has been transferred is to compare the count(*) of the db with the number of items in your file. The more advanced way is to compute hash (eg. sha1) of primary key sets.

Comment: I'm actually reading pretty structure data, which is imported from another database. Assume I'm reading test_db.sql file and the total size of the file is 10GB. So it require huge amount of time to import in the mysql DB. What I want a efficient way to import data in the database. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html), this is a standard MySql Loader Tools. It's work fine and faster. there are many options.

You can use :

- data file named export_du_histo_complet.txt with multiple line like this :
      "xxxxxxx.corp.xxxxxx.com";"GXTGENCDE";"GXGCDE001";"M_MAG105";"TERMINE";"2013-06-27";"14:08:00";"14:08:00";"00:00:01";"795691"
- sql file with (because I use Unix Shell which call SQL File) :

  ```
  LOAD DATA INFILE '/home2/soron/EXPORT_HISTO/export_du_histo_complet.txt'
          INTO TABLE du_histo
  FIELDS 
          TERMINATED BY ';'
          ENCLOSED BY '"'
          ESCAPED BY '\\'
  LINES
          STARTING BY ' '
          TERMINATED BY '\n'
  (server, sess, uproc, ug, etat, date_exploitation, debut_uproc, fin_uproc, duree, num_uproc)
  ```

I specified the table fields which i would import (my table has more columns)

- Note that exist [MySql bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39115), so you can't use variable to specify your INFILE.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Could you give me a precise example. Assume, my dataset is test_file.sql and if I want to import whole file by LOAD DATA, what SQL command I shall run?

Comment: I edit my post, you can see more options in [the LOAD DATA link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) (official MySQL Manual 5.1).